# jquery split html in several .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Iam doing some tests with jquery and jQWidgets and tabs.

I will create the html-structure for the tabs with jquery .append in loops, but i got error message about structur in jQwidget. And the problem was how i was appending the html.

This example it just to simulate whats happening in my loops.

If i add the html like this

```
$('#jqxTabs').append('<ul><li>test</li><li>testar</li></ul><div id="test"></div><div id="testar"></div>');
```

Then its working, but if i add the html in several steps then i got error from jQwidget

```
$('#jqxTabs').append('<ul>');
$('#jqxTabs').append('<li>test</li><li>testar</li>');
$('#jqxTabs').append('</ul>');
$('#jqxTabs').append('<div id="test"></div><div id="testar"></div>');
```

Maybe this is some basic jquery limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) doesn't work that way, you can't append/insert the *opening* and *closing* tags separately. You should pass representation of an *element* to the `append` method so it can create an *Element*.

```
$('<ul></ul>') // generate an `ul` element
     .append('<li>test</li><li>testar</li>') // append some `li` elements to it
     .appendTo('#jqxTabs'); // append the `ul` to the target object
```

As @DavidThomas mentions in the comment section, you can also pass an object to the jQuery and it will use it for adding attributes and properties to the generated element:

```
$('<ul/>', {
    html: '<li>test</li><li>testar</li>' // jQuery calls the `html` method behind the scenes
}).appendTo('#jqxTabs');
```

Comment: You could also: `$('<ul />', { 'html' : '<li>test</li><li>test</li>'}).appendTo('#jqxTabs');`

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, thanks for mentioning that. I though the syntax can be confusing for OP.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't really considered it from that point of view; and, honestly, I'm not sure my suggestion is any 'better' (in any way), just an alternative is all.